# Сохранение файла RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

Сейчас если написать текст и нажать на кнопку сохранения появится `OpenFileDialog`. Если в этом же документе что-то дописать и опять нажать на кнопку сохранения, то нужно снова выбирать место сохранения. Как сделать чтобы при сохранении одного и того же файла не нужно было каждый раз создавать новый файл, а просто перезаписать уже текущий?

```
private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog svf = new SaveFileDialog();
        svf.Filter = "Text Files (.rtf)|*.rtf";
        svf.Title = "Save";
        if (svf.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(svf.FileName);
            sw.Write(richTextBox1.Text);
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string fileName;
private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName))
     {
         using (SaveFileDialog svf = new SaveFileDialog())
         {
             svf.Filter = "Text Files (.rtf)|*.rtf";
             svf.Title = "Save";
             if (svf.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
             {
                 fileName = svf.FileName;
                 richTextBox1.SaveFile(fileName);
             }
         }
     }
     else
     {
         richTextBox1.SaveFile(fileName);
     }
 }

 private void buttonNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     richTextBox1.Clear();
     fileName = null;
 }
```

Comment: Если я захочу новый документ создать, то нужна кнопка как бы для создания нового файла и richTextBox1.Clear(); совсем не то. Как создать кнопку которая будет создавать новый документ и не будет конфликтовать с вашим кодом?

Comment: Нужно еще обнулить переменную `fileName`: `richTextBox1.Clear();
            fileName = null;`

Comment: Для сохранения лучше использовать `richTextBox1.SaveFile(fileName);`

Comment: Почему и как тогда это сюда вставить?

Comment: `using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName))
        {
            sw.Write(richTextBox1.Text);
            sw.Close();
        }` нужно заменить этим: `richTextBox1.SaveFile(fileName);`. В первом случае сохраняется только текст, а так вместе с текстом сохраняется и форматирование текста. К тому же, сохраненный таким образом rtf файл можно обратно загрузить командой `richTextBox1.LoadFile(fileName);`

Comment: richTextBox1.SaveFile(fileName); - При сохранении происходит ошибка - Путь не может быть неопределенным.

Comment: Сначала нужно переменной `fileName` присвоить значение.

Comment: Вы можете обновить ответ с этими изменениями?