# Как задать правильное сохранение и открытие файла текста из программы и из Windows?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, richtextbox

Я повторил сохранение файла с форматированием как в ответе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/678502/549706 и по такой же схеме переделал код и для кнопки открытия. Все работает. Только вот хотелось бы, чтобы файл открывался не только, если я открою файл через кнопку "Открыть" в программе, а еще и ПКМ по файлу -> Открыть с помощью ->Моя программа. И еще подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать кнопку Сохранить как , чтобы допустим, если я пропишу file.rtf , то оно сохраняло форматирование, а если укажу там file.txt или file.ini , чтобы оно сохраняло в файлах только текстовые данные, по типу как в стандартном Блокноте?

Comment: Не задавайте два вопроса в одной теме. Вам следовало создать две отдельных темы.

Comment: Имя файла передаётся в [Command-Line Arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/main-command-line#command-line-arguments).

Answer (score 1):

**1. Выбор Вашей программы в контекстном меню "Открыть с помощью"**

Для начала нужно собраь exe приложение.

Откройте меню "Сборка" в Visual Studio и выберите "Создать проект <Название вашего проекта>.exe" -> Появится окно "Сохранить как" -> Нажмите кнопку "Сохранить".

Теперь можно выбрать путь до Вашей программы в контекстном меню.

**2. Реализация кнопки "Сохранить как"**

Вот пример кода.

```
using System.IO; // Для использования класса Path

// Обработчик кнопки "Сохранить как"
private void btnSaveAs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Открытие диалога для сохранения файла
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
    // Установка возможных форматов (rtf, txt, ini, можете добавить свои)
    saveFileDialog.Filter = "RTF Files (*.rtf)|*.rtf|Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|INI Files (*.ini)|*.ini";
    if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string fileName = saveFileDialog.FileName;
        string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower();
        
        // Обработка расширений
        if (fileExtension == ".rtf")
        {
            // Сохранение в формате RTF
            richTextBox1.SaveFile(fileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
        }
        else if (fileExtension == ".txt")
        {
            // Сохранение в формате TXT
            richTextBox1.SaveFile(fileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
        }
        else if (fileExtension == ".ini")
        {
            // Сохранение в формате INI
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Ссылка на документацию метода `RichTextBox.SaveFile` -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.savefile?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ , я понял как реализовывать кнопку "Сохранить как"!А вот насчет первого вопроса , я уже собирал .exe файл и выбирал его в  "Открыть с помощью", но вот таким способом у меня в программе  ничего не отображается. Если я открываю .rtf файл ( в котором уже есть текст) из своего приложения по кнопке "Открыть", то все отлично открывается , а вот если использовать: ПКМ по файлу -> Открыть с помощью ->Моя программа , то программа открывается с пустым RichTextBox. Я так понимаю нужно создать нужный обработчик события и задать правильное открытия файла.

Comment: Для ответа на первый вопрос нужно использовать [Command-Line Arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/main-command-line#command-line-arguments)

Comment: @2OneHouse, Если Вам помог мой ответ, пожалуйста поставьте на нём голос "За" или примите его, если не сложно